# Yacc - Rules are never reduced, why is it?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I am learning to work with YACC and there are some errors that, although I think I know what may cause them, I can't solve. The errors that I get are:
-Useless nonterminal
-Useless rule

For what I have read in other posts this is due to the rules not being reachable, but after checking it again I'm not able to see the problem. For what I see all the "rules" appear on both sides.

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int nLineas;

void yyerror(const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
int yylex(void);
FILE *yyin;

%}

%start programa

%union {
    int tipo;
    char nombre[30];
}

%token <tipo> NUM
%token CARACTER
%token CADENA
%token <nombre> ID
%token INT
%token DOUBLE
%token CHAR
%token FLOAT
%token IF
%token MAIN
%token ELSE
%token SCANF
%token PRINTF
%token DEFINE
%token INCLUDE
%token FOR
%token WHILE
%token DO
%token IGUAL
%token DIFERENTE
%token MAYOR
%token MENOR
%token ESIGUAL
%token ESDIFERENTE
%token MAYORIGUAL
%token MENORIGUAL
%token '(' ')'

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '<' '>'
//%left ">=" "<=" "==" "!=" "&&" "||" "!"
%left UNARIO

%%
//PROGRAMA
programa: DECLARACIONCONSTANTES DECLARACIONVARIABLES FUNCIONMAIN {printf("\nTodo correcto numero de lineas %d.\n",nLineas);}
    ;
//SECCIONES DEL PROGRAMA
//Declaracion de constantes
DECLARACIONCONSTANTES:          /*Vacia*/
                            |DECLARACIONCONSTANTE
                            DECLARACIONCONSTANTES
                            ;
DECLARACIONCONSTANTE:           '#' DEFINE ID NUM {printf("\nDeclaracion constante númerica.\n\n");}
                                |'#' DEFINE ID '"' CADENA '"' {printf("\nDeclaracion constante cadena.\n\n");}
                                //'#' DEFINE ID "'"  "'" {printf("Declaracion constante cadena.\n");} Ver como hacer letra sin que lo incluyan en otro tipo
                                ;

//Declaracion de variables
DECLARACIONVARIABLES:           /*Vacia*/
                                |DECLARACIONVARIABLE
                                DECLARACIONVARIABLES
                                ;
DECLARACIONVARIABLE:            INT ID ';' {printf("\nDeclaracion variable int.\n\n");}
                                |FLOAT ID ';' {printf("\nDeclaracion de variable float.\n\n");}
                                |CHAR ID ';' {printf("\nDeclaracion de variable char.\n\n");}
                                |CHAR ID '[' NUM ']' ';' {printf("\nDeclaracion de variable cadena de caracteres.\n\n");}
                                ;

//Funcion Main



FUNCIONMAIN:                    CABECERAMAIN '{' DECLARACIONVARIABLES INSTRUCCIONES '}'
                                ;
            
CABECERAMAIN:                   MAIN '(' ')' {printf("\nCabecera main.\n\n");}
                                ;

INSTRUCCIONES:                  /*Vacio*/
                                |INSTRUCCION
                                INSTRUCCIONES
                                ;
                
INSTRUCCION:                    DECLARACIONVARIABLES
                                |ID '+' '+' ';' {printf("\nInstruccion -> incremento.\n\n");}
                                |ID '-' '-' ';' {printf("\nInstruccion -> decremento.\n\n");}
                                |ASIGNACION
                                |VISUALIZACION
                                |CONDICIONAL
                                |MIENTRAS
                                |LECTURA
                                |EXPRESION
                                ;

CONDICIONAL:                    IF '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}' {printf("\nInstruccion condicional -> estructura if.\n\n");}
                                |IF '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}' ELSE '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}' {printf("\nInstruccion condicional -> estructura if/else.\n\n");}
                                ;
        
MIENTRAS:                       WHILE '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}' {printf("\nInstruccion condicional mientras -> estructura while.\n\n");}

ASIGNACION:                     ID IGUAL NUM ';' {printf("\nInstrucción de asignacion: idVariable ->expresion numerica.\n\n");}
                                |ID IGUAL CADENA ';' {printf("\nInstrucción de asignación: idVariable -> cadena.\n\n");}
                                //|ID '=' '"'  '"' {printf("Instrucción de asignación: idVariable -> cadena\n");} Ver como hacer letra sin que lo incluyan en otro tipo
                                ;
            
VISUALIZACION:                  PRINTF '(' ID ')' ';' {printf("\nInstruccion de visualizacion -> printf de una variable.\n\n");}
                                |PRINTF '(' CADENA ')' ';' {printf("\nInstruccion de visualizacion -> printf de una cadena.\n\n");}
                                ;
                
LECTURA:                        SCANF '(' VARIABLE ')' ';' {printf("\nInstruccion  de lectura -> scanf.\n\n");}

EXPRESION:                      VARIABLE OP_BOOLEANOS VARIABLE {printf("\nExpresion -> booleana.\n\n");}
                                |VARIABLE OP_NUMERICOS VARIABLE {printf("\nExpresion -> numerica.\n\n");}
                                ;

VARIABLE:                       TERM VARIABLE
                                ;

TERM:                           NUM
                                |CADENA
                                |ID
                                |OP_NUMERICOS
                                |OP_BOOLEANOS
                                |','
                                |'('
                                |')'
                                ;
    
OP_BOOLEANOS:                   '&&'
                                |'||'
                                |IGUAL
                                |DIFERENTE
                                |MAYOR
                                |MENOR
                                |ESIGUAL
                                |ESDIFERENTE
                                |MAYORIGUAL
                                |MENORIGUAL
                                ;

OP_NUMERICOS:                   '+'
                                |'-'
                                |'*'
                                |'/'
                                ;
                
                            
%%

int main()
{
    yyin = fopen("Pruebas.c", "r");
    if(yyin == NULL){
        printf("ERROR de apertura de fichero.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

This are some of the errors shown in the terminal.

```
yacc.y: warning: 8 useless nonterminals and 33 useless rules
yacc.y:93.1-11: warning: useless nonterminal: CONDICIONAL
yacc.y:97.1-8: warning: useless nonterminal: MIENTRAS
yacc.y:108.1-7: warning: useless nonterminal: LECTURA
yacc.y:93.40-48: warning: useless nonterminal: EXPRESION
yacc.y:108.43-50: warning: useless nonterminal: VARIABLE
yacc.y:114.33-36: warning: useless nonterminal: TERM
yacc.y:110.42-53: warning: useless nonterminal: OP_BOOLEANOS
yacc.y:111.43-54: warning: useless nonterminal: OP_NUMERICOS
yacc.y:93.33-135: warning: useless rule: CONDICIONAL: IF '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}'
yacc.y:94.34-168: warning: useless rule: CONDICIONAL: IF '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}' ELSE '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}'
yacc.y:97.33-150: warning: useless rule: MIENTRAS: WHILE '(' EXPRESION ')' '{' INSTRUCCIONES '}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all come from the rule

```
VARIABLE: TERM VARIABLE ;
```

Since there's no base case for `VARIABLE` (no rule that can match something that does not recursively contain another `VARIABLE`), this rule can never be matched or reduced, which means in turn that every other rule that must contain a `VARIABLE` can never be reduced.

If you change this to

```
VARIABLE: TERM | TERM VARIABLE ;
```

then the 'useless' warnings will all go away, but you have a very large number of conflicts (for a variety of reasons).

You also have a lot of rules that are (pointlessly) right-recursive.  For yacc and bison (and LR parsing in general), you should prefer using left-recursive rules, as they are more efficient.